# Tk grid won't resize properly

Tags: python, grid, resize, tkinter

I'm trying to write a simple ui with Tkinter in python and I cannot get the widgets within a grid to resize. Whenever I resize the main window the entry and button widgets do not adjust at all.

Here is my code:

```
 class Application(Frame):
     def __init__(self, master=None):
         Frame.__init__(self, master, padding=(3,3,12,12))
         self.grid(sticky=N+W+E+S)
         self.createWidgets()

     def createWidgets(self):
         self.dataFileName = StringVar()
         self.fileEntry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.dataFileName)
         self.fileEntry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)
         self.loadFileButton = Button(self, text="Load Data", command=self.loadDataClicked)
         self.loadFileButton.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)

         self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
         self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
         self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

 app = Application()
 app.master.title("Sample Application")
 app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add a root window and columnconfigure it so that your Frame widget expands too.  That's the problem, you've got an implicit root window if you don't specify one and the frame itself is what's not expanding properly.

```
root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
app = Application(root)
```

Comment: added rowconfigure to allow vertical expand too

Answer (score 0):

I use pack for this. In most cases it is sufficient.
But  do not mix both!

```
class Application(Frame):
     def __init__(self, master=None):
         Frame.__init__(self, master)
         self.pack(fill = X, expand  =True)
         self.createWidgets()

     def createWidgets(self):
         self.dataFileName = StringVar()
         self.fileEntry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.dataFileName)
         self.fileEntry.pack(fill = X, expand = True)
         self.loadFileButton = Button(self, text="Load Data", )
         self.loadFileButton.pack(fill=X, expand = True)
```

Comment: I'll look into using pack instead of grid but from what I have read grid should work for resizing widgets as well.

Answer (score 0):

A working example.  Note that you have to explicitly set the configure for each column and row used, but columnspan for the button below is a number greater than the number of displayed columns.

```
## row and column expand
top=tk.Tk()
top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
for col in range(5):
    top.columnconfigure(col, weight=1)
    tk.Label(top, text=str(col)).grid(row=0, column=col, sticky="nsew")

## only expands the columns from columnconfigure from above
top.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
tk.Button(top, text="button").grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=10, sticky="nsew")
top.mainloop()
```